# Restart Azure WebApp using YAML Pipelines. There was a resource authorization issue

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to restart two Azure Web Applications when I run a Pipeline. I am trying to configure my YAML file to allow for this.

I'm getting the following error when attempting to run the pipeline:

> There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid. Job DEV_Deployment: Step input azureSubscription references service connection <> which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz. Job Gateway_DEV_Deployment: Step input azureSubscription references service connection <> which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to [https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."](https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.%22)

When I click the Authorize resources button I get a "Resources were successfully authorized" pop up but nothing happens. Even when I click "Rerun failed jobs" I get "no plan found for identifier"

I am new to CICD, and I'm not sure what I am missing. Can anyone help?

My code is below:

```
# Starter pipeline
trigger: none

jobs:
  - ${{if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'dev')}}:
    - deployment: "DEV_Deployment"
      displayName: "Start Deployment"  
      environment: "DEV"
      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      variables:
        - group: dev_vars
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
              - checkout: self              
              - task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
                displayName: "Restart 1st App Service"
                inputs:
                  azureSubscription: <<subscription name>>
                  Action: 'Restart Azure App Service'
                  WebAppName: <<web app 1 name>>
                  SpecifySlotOrASE: false
                  ResourceGroupName: <<resource group name>>
                  Slot: 'production'
              - task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
                displayName: "Restart 2nd App Service"
                inputs:
                  azureSubscription: <<subscription name>>
                  Action: 'Restart Azure App Service'
                  WebAppName: <<web app 2 name>>
                  SpecifySlotOrASE: false
                  ResourceGroupName: <<resource group name>>
                  Slot: 'production'
```

I was hoping this would run the deployment and restart the two web applications

Comment: `azureSubscription` needs to be an Azure Resource Manager service connection.

Comment: @ChenukaRatwatte Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your YAML code, it seems that you are directly inputting the Azure Subscription name to the `azureSubscription` field of the AzureAppServiceManage task.

The azureSubscription field needs to use the **Azure Resource Manager Type** service connection.

Refer to the following steps to solve the issue:

Step1: Navigate to **Project Settings -> Service Connections -> New Service Connection** and select the **Azure Resource Manager** option.

[image]

Step2: Select the related Azure Subscription and resource group in the drop down list. And input the name for the Service Connection

[image]

Step3: We can use the Azure Resource Manager Type Service connection name in the azureSubscription field of the AzureAppServiceManage task.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Connect to Microsoft Azure with an ARM service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops)